# Rails 4 / postgresql 9.4 - Query and update a ruby object inside an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a method (find_by_sql) that outputs **a ruby object inside an array** like this:

```
[#<deal id: 66480, opportunity_id: 4, admin_user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-09-20 18:37:29", updated_at: "2015-09-20 18:37:29", deal_available: true>]
```

How can I update the object's 'deal_available' attribute inside my database in raw postgresql ?

I tried different ways to write it but I stumble on the fact that it's very specific: it's an array, and inside there is a ruby object and I must manage to tell postgresql to **change the value of deal_available: true to deal_available: false.**

In local, I tried:  logger.debug "Here is the resulting object for update:

```
 #{@deal_question[0]}
```

but I get:

```
#<@deal_question:0x007fd9b3963270>
```

Here is how @deal_question is created

```
@deal_question = Deal.find_by_sql(
      " SELECT \"deals\".*
        FROM \"deals\"
        WHERE (opportunity_id = #{@deal.id}
        AND deal_available = true)
        ORDER BY \"deals\".\"id\" ASC LIMIT 1"
    )
```

I don't even have a postgresql query to suggest here because first I need to understand how to query this ruby object inside the array.

Comment: Why don't you use ActiveRecord instead of writing raw SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need a raw SQL query to update the `deal_available` attribute of your `@deal_question` object.

You can use [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) to achieve that.

```
# assuming @deal_question is an array
@deal_question[0].update_attributes(deal_available: false)
```

If you really want to use raw sql to update the attribute, then do this way:

```
array = [#<deal id: 66480, opportunity_id: 4, admin_user_id: 1, created_at: "2015-09-20 18:37:29", updated_at: "2015-09-20 18:37:29", deal_available: true>]
# grab the object to be updated
@deal_question = array[0]
# build the sql query string
sql = "UPDATE deals SET deal_available = false WHERE opportunity_id = #{@deal_question.id}"
# execute the sql to update the object
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: thanks, first suggestion did not work because it's only updating the objetc@deal question while I want to update the database. your second suggestion works. thanks!