# Update hash with Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an hash object:

```
@chosen_opportunity  = {"id"=>66480, "prize_id"=>4, "admin_user_id"=>1, "created_at"=>2015-09-20 18:37:29 +0200, "updated_at"=>2015-09-20 18:37:29 +0200, "opportunity_available"=>true}
```

How do I update the value of `deal_available` to false?

I tried this but it fails:

```
@chosen_opportunity['deal_available'] = false
@chosen_opportunity.save
```

controllers/deal_controller.rb:

```
def show_opportunity
    @deal =  Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])    

    @chosen_opportunity = Opoortunity.find_by_sql(
      " SELECT \"opportunities\".*
        FROM \"opportunities\"
        WHERE (deal_id = #{@deal.id}
        AND opportunity_available = true)
        ORDER BY \"opportunities\".\"id\" ASC LIMIT 1"
    ) 
    # comes from http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class
    @chosen_opportunity[0].attributes['opportunity_available'] = false
    @chosen_opportunity[0].save     


    respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
    end
  end
```

Can I update the value of `opportunity_available` from the Opportunity model inside a Deal controller? Is that why it's not working?

I know I could use Active Record but I need to use raw PostgreSQL for the first query. Thanks for your understanding of this non very Rails-y way.

Comment: You definitively need to work with ActiveRecord. I saw your other post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106585/rails-4-postgresql-9-4-query-and-update-a-ruby-object-inside-an-array), you're getting this hash by doing a raw SQL query that could easily be done with ActiveRecord. And Activercord objects can update the database, that's what they're meant to be.

Comment: is not very Rails-y but should be possible to use raw postgresql. insist on trying to manage to get this to work with postgresql.

Comment: Agreed that the raw SQL needs to be converted to use the ORM. One of the main points of using an ORM is to add a DB abstraction layer, allowing you to easily move your application from one DBM to another. As soon as you add raw SQL you begin tying yourself to a specific DBM and making it harder to move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code to:

```
@chosen_opportunity = Opportunity.find_by deal_id: deal.id, opportunity_available: true
@chosen_opportunity.opportunity_available = false
@chosen_opportunity.save!
```

This is much more Rails compatible. In addition, if I'm not mistaken, Rails won't let you save an object that you got through `find_by_sql`, so at the least you'd need to get a proper model object from the result. You can write (very ugly) code like:

```
Opportunity.where(id: @chosen_opportunity[0].attributes['id'])
           .update_all(opportunity_available: false)
```

**Warning**: This will update the database, but not the `@chosen_opportunity[0]` object.

Comment: is there other type of hashes than plain hashes? my hash comes from find_by_sql method that outputs an object http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class. deal question[0].attributes => outputs in local {"id"=>66480, "prize_id"=>4, "admin_user_id"=>1, "created_at"=>2015-09-20 18:37:29 +0200, "updated_at"=>2015-09-20 18:37:29 +0200, "deal_available"=>true}. is that what you call a plain hash? So to update it I use deal question[0].attributes['deal_available'] = false but it does not work

Comment: maybe it has sth to do with Rails 4 params_permit and strong parameters that do not let me update the value but i am not getting any strong parameter error in my commande terminal...

Comment: So basically you're just trying to update a model in the database. Can you post your complete code, including the part where you get the object from the DB?

Comment: yes will edit the question. trick is i'm trying to update a deal object inside another controller

Comment: Updated the answer. Unless you have a really good reason, I this you should change the find_by_sql to a proper find

Comment: i want it to work for hundreds if not thousands of simulteanous call to db. i know it's less railsy and hard to maintain but raw sql can be 50 times faster and in this precise case it's a tradeoff i want to make. for other quite god at rails who also chose to sometimes use raw sql https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/, or https://blog.codeship.com/speed-up-activerecord/ and https://blog.codeship.com/speed-up-activerecord/

Comment: would you be available to add a solution using the postgresql find_by_sql i was using? appreciate the help

Comment: sorry just saw the second part of your answer, thanks will try tomorriw your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `save` on a hash. You have to do it on the model that holds that hash as an instance variable.